# How do I copy and paste a formula in excel into a cell which is not adjacent to the initial cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The problem is that I have a data in sheet1 on the position of AB8 and AB9 and AC8 and AC9 and so on so the only change is column letter. In the sheet n2 I need to input following formula = AB8/AB9 and copy paste it every 5th column in sheet n2. The problem is that after each copy I need to increase the column letter by 1 when pasting formula. However, Excel is automatically pasting column AB8+5 so it is actually AG8 while I need column AC8 from the sheet1. Excel table is huge so doing it automatically is really painful experience and I believe that there is a way how to make a formula or VBA for it. Thank for any help. :)

Comment: So you *can* drag the formula, yes? You just want it calculating `AB8/AB9`, then `AB9/AB10`, `AB10/AB11`, etc?  But starting in Sheet 2, column A, then F, then K, etc.?

Comment: I want to copy formula AB8/AB9 from sheet one and insert it in every 5th column in sheet2 and add +1 column so A1 in sheet 2 will look like AB8/AB9 and A5 will be AC8/AC9 instead of AG8/AG9 as columns A1-A5 are filled with another data in sheet2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim rowIndex As Long, colIndex As Long

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your source sheet
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'change Sheet1 to your output sheet
    rowIndex = 1
    colIndex = 28               'set col number for Column AB

    With srcSht
        Do While .Cells(8, colIndex).Value <> ""   'loop through column AB to last column with data in row 8
            destSht.Cells(rowIndex, 1) = .Cells(8, colIndex) / .Cells(9, colIndex)
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 5     'increment row by 5
            colIndex = colIndex + 1     'increment column by 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```